# Diferencias entre direcciones MAC en dispisitivos móviles

Tags: android

Tengo un par de dudas, a raíz de un proyecto en Android que estoy realizando y uso la dirección Mac como identificador del celular.

¿Cuántas direcciones MAC tiene un dispotivo móvil?
Yo creo que tiene la mac del WIFI, la mac del Bluetooth y la mac de conexión telefónica (3g o lo que tenga). Pero de esto no estoy completamente seguro.

En este proyecto mientras usaba emuladores usé:

```
byte[] mac = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().nextElement().getHardwareAddress();

String macAddress = "";
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
    macAddress += String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? ":" : "");
}
```

para obtener la dirección mac del dispositivo, pero cuando empecé a probar con dispositivos reales, me retornaba null, así que usé:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String macAddress = info.getMacAddress();
```

para obtener la dirección mac, me queda claro que esta última es la dirección mac de la tarjeta de wifi. Entonces la dirección mac que hallaba con getHardwareAddress(), ¿qué dirección hallaba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero imprimas el valor con los metodos posibles ya que debe ser la misma, regularmente se usa este método:

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo info = manager.getConnectionInfo();
String miMAC = info.getMacAddress();
```

Si estas obteniendo null probablemente es porque omites el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Tu pregunta esta relacionada a un identificador unico, pero por experiencia te puedo comentar que aunque las Mac Address deben ser únicas, desgraciadamente en android se repiten en algunos dispositivos, en algunos otros la puede modificar el usuario, en otros no tiene valor e incluso he visto dispositivos con una Mac Address "4F", asi que este método no es confiable. Lo mismo para el IMEI.

Te sugiero veas este articulo de google:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html